# Code for testing user inputs in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
#loop to get input that is not blank, strips input of whitespace
def ckin(a):    
    while a=='':
        a=input().strip()
    return  a

#creates list with includes user admin
user_names = ['admin']  

#Ask for 5 names to store as usernames
print('Please enter 5 user names: ')    

#if username is valid, add to list
for i in range(0,5) 
    lib_name=input().strip()
    lib_name=ckin(lib_name)
    user_names.append(lib_name)

#asks for login name, must be valid
print('Enter login name:')  
log_name=input().strip()
log_name=ckin(log_name)

#Create a test list that is lower case to compare login
#against without altering the cases used by user to creat username list

test=[name.lower() for name in user_names] 

#if login name not in list continue to prompt
while log_name.lower() not in test:
    print('Enter login name:')
    log_name=input().strip()
    log_name=ckin(log_name)

#find login name in test, then return either response for admin, or login    name using 
#case formatting that original used for original entry
for i in range(len(test)):
    if log_name.lower() == 'admin':
        print('Hello admin, would you like to see a status report?')
        break
    elif log_name.lower() == test[i]:
        print('Hello '+user_names[i]+', thank you for logging in again')
        break
```

Looking for general review self-teaching, Day 4

I haven't learned much but I keep attempting to do what I'm learning with user inputs instead of set entries

My goal here was to be able to create a list that keeps the original entry cases to be used for responding. I created a second list in lower cases to compare to and then responded using the cases the entries were stored as.

Any comments are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can reduce your code duplication a bit. First, the way you are currently using the `ckin` function is like this:

```
name = input("Enter a name").strip()
name = ckin(name)
```

Wouldn't it be nicer to be able to do:

```
name = ask_user("Enter a name: ")
```

For this, just modify your function like this:

```
def ask_user(message=""):
    user_input = ""
    while not user_input:
        user_input = input(message).strip()
    return user_input
```

Note that I renamed it (to make it clearer what it does), used the fact that empty strings are falsy and added whitespace around the `=` operator, as recommended by Python's official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

---

Going further, you should get into the habit of defining clearly named functions for separate things.

One such concern is getting a pre-populated username list. Currently this list is populated with user input, but this might change in the future. So it would be nice to bundle that part all together in one function:

```
def get_users():
    # creates a users set, which always includes admin
    users = {'admin'}

    #Ask for 5 names to store as usernames
    print('Please enter 5 unique user names: ')
    while len(users) < 6:
        users.add(ask_user("Enter a valid user name: ").lower())
    return users
```

Note that I made the datastructure a `set` here, which gives you \$\mathcal{O}(1)\$ time complexity for `in` tests. I also made sure that there are actually 5 + 1 users (in other words, user names need to be unique). I also put the `str.lower` transformation here so we don't need to do it later and only store the canonical user name.

---

Next is a login function, that asks for a username until a valid one is entered:

```
def login(users):
    user_name = None
    while user_name not in users:
        user_name = ask_user("Enter login name: ").lower()
    return user_name
```

---

And then, the greeting. Instead of iterating over all users until you reached the user that is currently logging in, use the fact that we already know that the user is in `users` (since we explicitly checked for that in `login`). So this becomes a simple `if..else` check:

```
def print_greeting(user_name):
    if user_name == 'admin':
        print('Hello admin, would you like to see a status report?')
    else:
        print(f'Hello {user_name}, thank you for logging in again')
```

Here I used an [`f-string`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498), as introduced in Python 3.6, to make the string formatting a bit easier.

---

And finally, tying it all together in a `main` function:

```
def main():
    users = get_users()
    user_name = login(users)
    print_greeting(user_name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Note that I call this `main` function only under a [`if __name__ == "__main__":` guard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do). This ensures that the `main` function does not run if you import from this script in another script.

Comment: Thank you this is exciting! This is my first time seeing the `while not` and I sort of grasp the idea of `main` here,  definitely going to review this and integrate these concepts.

Comment: could you breakdown the use of `=""` in this portion of the code, I understand what is being done, checked, and returned just not what is happening with the `=""` in the `ask_user` function

Comment: @anthonyvalva: It just sets `user_input` to a value where the `while` loop's condition is met, so the user is asked for the first time. I also could have put `user_input = input(message).strip()` there as well, but that would then be repeated (so if you ever e.g. want to change that the user input is not only stripped, but also lowercased, you would need to remember to change it in both places, making it a bit harder to maintain).

Comment: I'm sorry I was actually reffering to the `message=''` portion what does this do?

Comment: @anthonyvalva The `message=''` default keyword argument is used as input prompt in the call of the `input()` built-in instead of using a `print()` statement beforehand.

Comment: @RichardNeumann Thank you, what are the benefits of this over just using `ask_user(message):`?

Comment: @anthonyvalva  That `message` has a default value so if you don't want to add any prompt, you can just call `ask_user()` without any argument

Comment: @Graipher that is what I was thinking, to call `ask_user` when we don't  need a message, just didn't want to make any incorrect assumptions. Is this `ask_user` format one of the more agreed upon formats for requesting infomation?

Comment: @anthonyvalva: More or less, yes. You will almost always find a similar loop, sometimes expressed as a `while True` loop, especially if the input validation includes parsing the user input e.g. as an `int`. See for example my answer [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/200046/98493) for some more complex user input validation.

Comment: @Graipher what are you referring to in this and the linked post, when you speak of 0(1) complexity and 0(n) complexity , you mention range during this.

Comment: @anthonyvalva It means that (in the worst case), `100 in range(101)` takes a hundred times longer than `0 in range(1)`, because it needs to iterate through the list and see if each element is the one out are looking for, so it scales with the length of the list (note that `range` returned a `list` in Python 2, so this is not a good example in Python 3). In comparison, `100 in set(range(101))` takes constant time (when doing the initialization of the set before), regardless of the size of the set.

Comment: @anthonyvalva Have a look [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) for an overview over the most used data structures and their time complexities.

Answer (score 7):

## General

Read and familiarize yourself with

- [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)
- Functions
- The `if __name__ == '__main__':` check

Make sure, the function and variable names convey their purpose.

## Specific

The user input check could be done a little more pythonic:

```
def get_user_name():
    user_name = None
    while not user_name:
        user_name = input().strip()
    return user_name
```

And thus, the first *manual* reading can be omitted:

```
for i in range(5):
    # lib_name = input().strip()  # Useless
    lib_name = get_user_name()
    user_names.append(lib_name)
```

Same here:

```
print('Enter login name:')  
log_name = get_user_name()
```

For quicker lookup of data, use a hasing container:

```
known_user_names = frozenset(name.lower() for name in user_names)

#if login name not in list continue to prompt
while log_name.lower() not in known_user_names:
    print('Unknown user. Enter valid login name:')  # Add an error hint to the user.
    log_name = get_user_name()
```

The loop here is useless:

```
for i in range(len(test)):
    if log_name.lower() == 'admin':
        print('Hello admin, would you like to see a status report?')
        break
    elif log_name.lower() == test[i]:
        print('Hello '+user_names[i]+', thank you for logging in again')
        break
```

Above you already made sure, that the user name is known.

```
if log_name.lower() == 'admin':
    print('Hello admin, would you like to see a status report?')
else:
    print('Hello', log_name + ', thank you for logging in again')
```

Comment: going to review all this and applyt it, greatly appreciate your time!

Comment: Maybe wait for some other reviews first.